# supported authentication methods available (server sent: publickey)

Tags: server, ssh

I received admin user credentials to Ubuntu server, but when i try to ssh to it i get *"FATAL ERROR: No supported authentication methods available (server sent: publickey)"*.

the command that i used (on a local windows machine):

```
plink -ssh root@172.31.100.7 -pw "mypassword"
```

Since i cannot login to the server, i cannot edit `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` or add `authorized_keys`. And none of my colleagues are able to connect.

Would would be the workaround? the Ubuntu server is in Azure cloud and there is an option to connect via serial console. is it possible to somehow use it without causing any disruption of the services (this is a production server)?

Answer (score 2):

> server sent: publickey

The server is expecting a ssh key, not a password, that matches a key on file.

Notify the admin who created the server for you. They must fix the problem by loading your public ssh keys or enabling passwords.

- Passwords have a higher risk of compromise. Keys are wise.

If you are the admin who created the server and are locked out, use the Azure web page to regain access...or wipe it and create a new instance.